by cooking or while cooking?
Is the second sentence grammatically correct?

They chatted about their day at work while cooking dinner.

They chatted about their day at work by cooking dinner.



It might be 'grammatically' correct, but it is pure nonsense.

We don't do corrections per se and you have to make an effort. Please look up by in the dictionary. We soothed our nerves by cooking. by introduces an agent or activity.

In other words, cooking dinner is not a means of chatting.

I'm curious why you think by might work there.  Are you thinking of "They walked by the stream" where "by" means "alongside"  and transposing that to your dinner cooking situation, thinking by could be used to express the notion that one activity was performed alongside another activity?

The first sentence is correct in this scenario. It is roughly equivalent to

They chatted about their day at work [at the same time as they were] cooking dinner.

The second sentence is grammatically correct, but it has a different meaning and doesn't make sense here. "I did X by doing Y" suggests that Y was the method or the means with which I accomplished X. For example, the sentence

She prepared for the week by cooking her lunches ahead of time.

means that cooking her lunches was how she prepared for the week.
